# How to show that Newton's method has the linear convergence rate with 1-1/m?

Tags: convergence-divergence

How to show that Newton's method has the linear convergence rate with 1-1/m ? (For a zero of multiplicity m>=2)

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=(x-a)^mg(x)$, with $g(x)\neq0$